# Idiomatic way of handling const template arguments in function templates

Tags: c++, c++20

For a framework project I'm working on, I provide an interface for users to access objects through a handle-like interface--i.e. they do not own the objects themselves, but they need to use them.

The class the user cares about looks something like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class handle {
public:
  using value_type = std::remove_const_t<T>;
  using const_pointer = value_type const*;
  using const_reference = value_type const&;

  // Pointer-like API; const-only access
  const_pointer operator->() const noexcept { return ptr_; }
  const_reference operator*() const noexcept { return *ptr_; }

  // See explanation in post...
  template <typename U, typename V>
  friend bool operator==(handle<U> u, handle<V> v)
    requires std::same_as<typename handle<U>::value_type, 
                          typename handle<V>::value_type>;

  // Constructor and other member functions hidden.

private:
  const_pointer ptr_;
};
```

The handle is constructed by the framework, and the user has only `const` access to the object through the handle.  For an `int` owned by the framework, it is therefore immaterial whether a user specifies (e.g.) `handle<int>` or `handle<int const>`, as the interface will be identical for each.

The question is, how do I simply create an equality function that supports potentially `const`-qualified template arguments.  IOW, I need:

```cpp
handle<int> hi{...};
handle<int const> hic{...};
assert(hi == hic);
```

The closest I've come up with is to create a free function template that has access to `ptr_`:

```cpp
template <typename U, typename V>
bool operator==(handle<U> u, handle<V> v)
  requires std::same_as<typename handle<U>::value_type, typename handle<V>::value_type>
{
      return u.ptr_ == v.ptr_;
}
```

But this is a lot of boilerplate!  Is there a better way to handle this problem using modern C++?

Comment: The `requires` clause doesn't seem like too much boilerplate. If that's the only issue you have, I think you're overanalyzing things.

Comment: Do you want `handle<int>` and `handle<const int>` to be distinct types?  If not, maybe use a type alias like `template<typename T> using handle = detail::handle_impl<std::remove_const_t<T>>`.

Comment: The simplest solution is to disallow things like `handle<int const>` – it has no actual value, only inherent code complexity. A single `static_assert` or `requires` here will correctly punt the problem to the user.

Comment: @ildjarn, I think you may be correct.  Unless `handle<int>` and `handle<int const>` are intended to behave differently, then it's probably best to forbid the `const`-qualified specialization.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just write a member comparison:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct handle {
    using value_type = std::remove_const_t<T>;
    using const_pointer = value_type const*;

    template <class U>
    friend struct handle;

    template <class U>
        // this can be same_as<T const, U const>, etc.
        requires std::equality_comparable_with<T*, U*>
    bool operator==(handle<U> rhs) const {
        return ptr == rhs.ptr;
    }

private:
    const_pointer ptr;
};
```

With the new C++20 comparison rules, this is sufficient to give you both homogeneous and heterogeneous `==` and `!=`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T78v1GGr1)

---

A simpler approach would be:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct handle {
    using value_type = T;
    using const_pointer = value_type const*;

    friend bool operator==(handle, handle) = default;

private:
    const_pointer ptr;
};

template <class T> struct handle<T const> : handle<T> { };
```

Here, `handle<int const>` and `handle<int>` are separate types (even if `handle<int const>` is silly), but `handle<int const>` is a `handle<int>` so the inherited comparison just works. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b77fjd1f4).

Comment: I love the simplicity of your solution, <s>but...I cannot access `rhs.ptr`, presumably because `handle<U>` is a different type than that of `*this`</s>.  Nevermind, missed the friend declaration above.

Comment: @KyleKnoepfel Heh, yep :-) Added a simpler approach too.